# Having some trouble passing an entire array through a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function

Fairly simple problem I'm having that I can't get my head around. I'm trying to pass an entire array into a function, and it's giving me a syntax error. But I honestly can't see the error, even though it's clearly right in front of me.

Function Declaration:

```
void insertWholeStruct(StoredData temp[]);
```

Function Definition:

```
void Array::insertWholeStruct(StoredData temp[])
{
    for(int i=0;i<arrSize;i++)
    {

        arr[i] = temp[i].id;
        }
    }
```

Function call, where the error is:

```
test.insertWholeStruct(testData[]);
```

Comment: `test.insertWholeStruct(testData);`

Comment: Where is `arrSize` defined? It should probably be passed to the function. Also what is the definition of `arr` and `StoredData`?

Comment: You will need to pass the size of the array as an argument. `temp[]` as a function parameter is a pointer.

Comment: You need a breeze of fresh "Beginner C++ Tutorial".

Comment: WorldsWorstProgrammer LOL man.. what a name.

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun at least it's descriptive.

Comment: Using C++ - Use both vectors and references

Comment: There's a `std::array` and `std::vector` for known and unknown at compile time sizes. Use those.

Comment: You are probably coming from a Java background or you are a totally new programmer that is what caused the confusion. Array sizes should be known at compile-time in C/C++. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `[]` after `testData` in the function call.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in the way you try to pass the argument in the function.
Your compiler is complaining for not knowing at compile time the size of the array you
are trying to pass. Pass by pointer the array and this is alliviated.

**It should be instead :**

```
//no need to define pointer name in declaration
void insertWholeStruct(StoredData *);


//function definition should change only a little bit
void insertWholeStruct(StoredData *temp)
{

   for(int i=0;i<arrSize;i++)
   {
       arr[i] = temp[i].id;
   }
}
```